# Copy a range of data rows to another datatable - C#

Tags: c#, mysql, datatable

I have a data table that contains 100 rows, I want to copy a range of rows(31st row to 50th row) to another data table.

I am following below logic.

```
DataTable dtNew = table.Clone();
for(int k=30; k < 50 && k < table.Rows.Count; k++)
{
     dtNew.ImportRow(table.Rows[k]);
}
```

Is there any better approach to do this?

Comment: What type is table?

Comment: @GiladReich DataTable i reckon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's about readability, then a good idea would be to throw this into an extension method.
Without changing your logic:

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void CopyRows(this DataTable from, DataTable to, int min, int max)
    {
        for (int i = min; i < max && i < from.Rows.Count; i++)
            to.ImportRow(from.Rows[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you can always reuse it without all the fancy syntax and know that it does exactly what you need if there is a concern of performance:

```
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt1.CopyRows(dt2, 30, 50);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `LINQ` you can do something like:

```
DataTable dtNew = table.Select().Skip(31).Take(20).CopyToDataTable();
```

Performance wise, using LINQ wont do any better, it however makes it more readable.

**EDIT:** Added handling check

```
int numOFEndrow = 20;
int numOfStartRow = 31;
if (table.Rows.Count > numOFEndrow +numOfStartRow)
{
    DataTable dtNew = table.Select().Skip(numOfStartRow).Take(numOFEndrow).CopyToDataTable();
}
```

Comment: If in any situation table count<50 rows?

Comment: @RamaKrishna, You will get an exception, so you have to handle it